# How to concat string and float

Tags: c++, stm32

I have a simple variable:

```
float t = 30.2f;
```

How do I add it to a string?

```
char* g = "Temperature is " + h?
```

Any guaranteed way (I don't have Boost for instance, and unsure of what version of c++ I have) I can get this to work on a microcontroller?

Comment: Aside: A c-like approach would use `char buf[15 + 12 + 1]; snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,  "Temperature is %g", t);`.

Comment: Is `h` a `float`?  Or did you intend to use `t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple cases, you can just use the `std::string` class and the `std::to_string` function, which have both been part of C++ for a long time.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  float t = 30.2;
  std::string r = "Temperature is " + std::to_string(t);
  std::cout << r;
}
```

However, `std::to_string` doesn't give you much control over the formatting, so if you need to specify a field width or a number of digits after the decimal point or something like that, it would be better to see lorro's answer.

If you have an incomplete implementation of the C++ standard library on your microcontroller so you can't use the functions above, or maybe you just want to avoid dynamic memory allocation, try this code (which is valid in C or C++):

```c
float t = 30.2;
char buffer[80];
sprintf(buffer, "Temperature is %f.", t);
```

Note that `buffer` must be large enough to guarantee there will never be a buffer overflow, and failing to make it large enough could cause crashes and security issues.

Comment: I *definitely* recommend the `sprintf()` implementation at the end of this answer for a microcontroller. Do _not_ use dynamic memory allocation and large C++ objects in a memory-constrained environment, especially if it's a safety-critical device, which microcontrollers frequently are used in.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << t;
std::string s = "Temperature is " + oss.str();
```

Then you can use either the string or the `c_str()` of it (as *`const`* `char*`).

If, for some reason, you don't have standard library, you can also use `snprintf()` et. al. (printf-variants), but then you need to do the buffer management yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, C++20 introduces [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) for fluent string formatting of this sort:

```
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    float t = 30.2f;
    std::string s = std::format("Temperature is {}!\n", t);
    std::cout << s;
}
```

Do note that compiler support for the format library is still underway. GCC does not yet support it, and Clang only has [experimental support](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html#note-p0645)<sup>1</sup> in 14.0+.

<sub><sup>1</sup> requires LLVM to be compiled with `-DLIBCXX_ENABLE_INCOMPLETE_FEATURES=ON`</sub>